# Session authentication with cookies in Django not working

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

I am using Session Authentication for my Django REST API. What I want is to be able to access self.request.user every time an API call is received at any of my endpoints, so I can process user generated content.

From the docs, it seems session authentication stores only session id's in cookies, but does not send any data beyond that. So, even after I log in, the subsequent requests I send are user-anonymous.

One solution is to send the username and password every time a call is made from the origin, which I think is probably not good practice.

How can I go about persisting user in a session?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JWT Authentication and send the token with every request, this way you can access `request.user` in your code.